# confirm alert not working 

Tags: php, javascript

I want the work of the Control Panel in my site for members ...

I designed the page is displayed all the registered members on my site

And  i but it  checkbox front each member name ,becuase it allowed  to select multiple name then click delete button The following code works

but now i want confirm alert  before delete code working

even , if clicked on ok the deletion is working  , and if  clicked on cancel  the  is not working ..

how  i can work it ?

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
?>
  <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['MemberID']; ?>"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['MemberName']; ; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php
}

?>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="delete"  onclick="javascript:return confirm('are you sure to delete this record???? ')"/></td>
</tr>

<?php

$delete = $_REQUEST['delete'];
$checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox'];
$count = count($_REQUEST['checkbox']);

// Check if delete button active, start this
if($delete) {

    echo "<script language=\"Javascript\">\n";
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];


        $sql = "Delete  FROM members where MemberID ='$del_id'";

        $sq2 = "Delete FROM joinroom where  MemberID ='$del_id'";

        $result1 = mysql_query($sql);
        $result2 = mysql_query($sq2);

        echo "else {\n";
        echo "alert ('Nothing deleted');\n }";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot.........

Comment: That `javascript:` pseudoprotocol is by the way superfluous. Remove it.

Comment: Quoting your question: *even if clicked on ok the deletion is working , and if clicked on cancel the [deletion] is not working*. Isn't it the intended behavior?

Comment: I actually didn't pay attention to his question as his English was unparseable, so I just skipped ahead to the code. The JS code which he attempted to print using PHP at the bottom is syntactically invalid. For the remnant it looks ok, apart from the SQL injection hole.

Comment: @BalusC Actually I think it's valid Javascript. `javascipt:` should be interpreted as a [labeled statement](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.12). It's useless but probably harmless.

Comment: Thank you for your sympathy with me ....

But I want to know what you have to in order to function as required so that Alert is appear and the record is delation  only if you click on OK

Comment: @Alex: it's valid, but superfluous (useless).

Answer (score 1):

PHP and Javascript doesn't run in sync as you seem to think. PHP runs at the server side, produces a bunch of template text with embedded HTML/CSS/JS, sends it over network from server to client side using HTTP protocol. Once arrived at client side, the JS starts to get interpreted and executed. Rightclick page in your webbrowser and do *View Source*. It'll become more clear. You'll see a good JS syntax error.

By the way, sanitize your inputs. This is a good [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) hole.

Comment: Is not clear to me your idea as required ....


 
Which I understood from your speech that it is difficult to do so????
Do not they?

Comment: I hope your help me ...

I am not experienced enough 


Tell me where the error even I modified it to you that I tested the code he's working, but if you click on the button twice for two successive
 (I mean that if you specifically and then clicking on button and you choose ok the first time, but if you have the same work is again ........ it works, it is perplexing indeed

Comment: Open page in webbrowser, execute the delete, rightclick page and choose *View Source*, head to the `<script>` which you generated with PHP. Does it look valid? Does the `else{` belong there? Fix it accordingly.

Comment: Please ..... How do I make this script work properly, so ask me before the deletion

To date, I could not reach the correct solution......